# How to ignore background noise while recording audio using pyaudio in python?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am using the following code to record audio in python, it works perfectly. But when I set the microphone input volume to high, the audio thus recorded using this code has a lot of noise. How to get rid of this noise??

```
import pyaudio
import wave

def record(filename):
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 16000
    CHUNK = 1024
    RECORD_SECONDS = 15
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = filename 

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # start Recording
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    print("recording...")
    print('---------------------------------')
    print(int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS))
    print('*********************************')

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
    print("Recording finished. . .")

    # stop Recording
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    waveFile.setsampwidth(2)  
    audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
    waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
    waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    waveFile.close()
```

Comment: You can of course add some processing, cf https://gist.github.com/PandaWhoCodes/9f3dc05faee761149842e43b56e6ee8c, but this is only a duck-tape solution.  The proper solution is audio-engineering 101: get a clean signal to start with (set your mic level lower, use a better mic / mic preamp / soundcard etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already tried changing the mic volume manually and it works fine, but I don't want to do change mic volume manually that's why I'm looking for some other alternative.

Comment: Well, as I already mentionned, "other alternatives" are not going to really improve a bad signal (junk in, junk out...) - even with today's most advanced signal processing technologies removing hiss and noises a posteriori will _always_ degrade the signal one way or another (and usually in more than one way). This might not be of huge importance if all you want is more or less intelligible speech (you can vastly reduce the bandwidth and dynamic and still get something more or less usable), but if you need a truly clean signal then you have to fix it at the source.

Answer (score 0):

This: [noisereduce](https://pypi.org/project/noisereduce/) allows for a wide range of filtering you can apply to your raw audio data before saving to stream/file. However the previous answers aren't wrong. Augmenting the audio stream is always a bit 'hacky'.